# Git and parallel branches

Tags: git, dvcs

I am using git and I have a local develop branch, from which I created new branch called `BranchA`, where I will work on `FeatA`. I worked on this feature, and I needed some additional input, so I needed to postpone work until I receive information I required. So I committed to `BranchA`, and created new branch `BranchB` from `Develop` branch. This resulted in having two parallel branches created from Develop branch.

Now I received additional information for `FeatA`, so I reverted to `BranchA`, and finished FeatA. At this point I merged Develop branch with BranchA, pushed it to origin/Develop, and now I wish to continue developing on BranchB.

Do I need to "rebase" BranchB, so that its now based on "new" Develop branch, the one that contains FeatA also? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: git checkout branchB; git rebase FeatA;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to? No. Why would you? If there are conflicts you can solve them when merging. If you need the features of BranchA in BranchB, then you can do this by (squash-)merging or rebasing (or even cherry-picking).

Have you pushed you BranchB to a remote? If so, you should not rebase your branch, unless you know what you are doing.

You might want to get a better understanding of how git works. I recommend the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)

Comment: Thanks. I have not pushed BranchB. So, if I am working in BranchB, and I wish to commit and merge on finish, there would be no problem with Merging with Develop than now also contains FeatA? FeatA will not be lost?

Comment: @Goran why would it be lost? Wouldn't that undermine the whole point of a version control system? Please read up on git and branching https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell